# =TODAY() Function not working with code for date criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I am working with to create a new table based on criteria (department and date) from an original table.  The MaxDate works when I put in a specific date "8/4/2020", but not when I try and use the "=TODAY()" function.  Any ideas?

```vb
Sub DepartmentSearch()
    
    Department = "IT"
    MaxDate = "=TODAY()"

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange  ' source table
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Department  ' filter Department
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<" & MaxDate  ' filter date
    rng.Copy  ' copy filtered rows
    Range("Z2").Select ' source table
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False  ' paste values to target table
    rng.AutoFilter ' turn off filter on source table

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating formulas and VBA.

That said, just use `Date`:

```vb
MaxDate = Date
```