# Using an IfError with PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I used the code suggested by BigBen, and it works great by itself, but when duplicated for a different TeamRole it has a duplicate declaration in current scope error.  Anything to fix this?

Sub DepartmentSearch2()

' Environmental

```
Sheets.Add.Name = ("Environmental")
Sheets("Environmental").Activate

TeamRole = "Environmental"
MaxDate = Date

Dim table As ListObject
Set table = Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("Table1")

table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=TeamRole
table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<" & MaxDate

On Error Resume Next
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Set rngToCopy = table.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
    rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Environmental").Range("A2")
End If

table.Range.AutoFilter
```

' Assembly Engineer

```
Sheets.Add.Name = ("Assembly Engineer")
Sheets("Assembly Engineer").Activate

TeamRole = "Assembly Engineer"
MaxDate = Date

Dim table As ListObject
Set table = Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("Table1")

table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=TeamRole
table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<" & MaxDate

On Error Resume Next
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Set rngToCopy = table.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
    rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Assembly Engineer").Range("A2")
End If

table.Range.AutoFilter
```

End Sub

Comment: You can't paste a table object into a worksheet formula. Use VBA to determine if the `rng` object is worth copying. If not, use VBA to write into the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note (as a follow-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248574/today-function-not-working-with-code-for-date-criteria/63248590#63248590)) that you are still conflating formulas and VBA. `=IFERROR()` is formula syntax, not VBA.

That said, perhaps try the following. It will only copy the *visible* rows from the *body* of the table after you've filtered, if there are indeed any visible rows.

```vb
Dim table As ListObject
Set table = Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("Table1")

table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=TeamRole
table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<" & MaxDate

On Error Resume Next
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Set rngToCopy = table.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
    rngToCopy.Copy Destination:= Sheets("Assembly Engineer").Range("A2")
End If

table.Range.AutoFilter
```

Comment: This code worked great by itself, but when I tried to add another TeamRole, it would have a duplicate error...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: I edited my question above, hopefully it makes more sense

Comment: You can't have two instances of `Dim table As ListObject`.